# #openshift server unavailable 503 error

Tags: 503-error, openshift-online-2

I have application created on TOMCAT7 (JBOSS EWS) using Mysql DB. My application keeps getting 503 error (service unavailable)

[WARNING] 033/104029 (124189) : Server express/local-gear is DOWN, reason: Layer7 timeout, check duration: 10001ms. 0 active and 0 backup servers left. 0 sessions active, 0 requeued, 0 remaining in queue.
[ALERT] 033/104029 (124189) : proxy 'express' has no server available!

I always restart the app and this gets resolved. However, after few hours I see the issue again.

Appreciate your help as I am pretty new to this error and server side config.

Answer (score 0):

The problem might be that you're not serving anything at the root of your express app, so you need to modify haproxy configuration file, find the file that mentions express and httpchk and change from / to something that responds to request.

Alternatively, just serve something up on / so HAProxy doesn't keep restarting your service.